# Can I use .trigger("change") in order to update a checkbox prior to the event handler finishing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, triggers

Basically, I have a grid that contains a bunch of items, and all of these items contain a checkbox to the left. These checkboxes are bound to a function I called `ecuDataBound()`, which contains event handlers that call a function called `onChangeECU`. I've noticed that the state of a checkbox being activated isn't done until after the event handler finishes running in its entirety - I'm wondering if there's a way to change the state of the checkbox prematurely.

Specifically, I read something about a `.trigger("change")` function that might be what I'm looking for, but I'm not sure I'm using it correctly or for the correct problem.

```
function ecuDataBound() {
    $('#ECUs .k-checkbox:not(:first)').on('click', onChangeECU);
}
```

```
function onChangeECU(arg) {
    // ...
    grid.trigger("change");
    isSelected = checkForSelection("#ECUs");
    // ...
}
```

```
function checkForSelection(gridID) {
    const inputString = gridID + " tr.k-state-selected";
    const isSelected = $(inputString).length;
    if (isSelected) {
        return true;
    }
```

Because the state of the checkboxes isn't updated until its event handler is completely done running, the function `checkForSelection` doesn't work as intended for the first run through. Can I use `.trigger("change")` in this context or am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Please let me know if I have worded this in a confusing way and if I need to elaborate on any more details. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than depending on another class `.k-state-selected` I would look directly at the checkbox. You said the check box is contained within the row. So what you can probably do is something along the lines of this:

```
function ecuDataBound() {
    // change trigger from 'click' to 'change'
    $('#ECUs .k-checkbox:not(:first)').on('change', onChangeECU);
}

function onChangeECU(arg) {
    // ...
    // remove trigger
    // grid.trigger("change");
    isSelected = checkForSelection("#ECUs");
    // ...
}

function checkForSelection(gridID) {
    // change " tr.k-state-selected"
    const inputString = gridID + ' .k-checkbox:checked';
    // good idea to turn into actual boolean with > 0 check
    const isSelected = $(inputString).length > 0;
    if (isSelected) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if this exactly what you are looking for. Please let me know if this off the wall and nowhere near what you expect.

**NOTE:** Comments are made inline in the code itself

Comment: It turns out the only thing I needed to get my code working the way I wanted was the change from `click` to `change`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than recording `click`s on each checkbox, consider using event delegation. The idea is to capture the `click` on the parent element. Then the checkbox states will be maintained.

Here is one solution using plain JavaScript:

```js
document.querySelector('#ECUs').addEventListener('click', doIt);

function doIt() {
  let checked = document.querySelectorAll('#ECUs input:checked');
  checked.forEach(c => console.log(c.value));
}
```

```html
<div id="ECUs">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1">Check 1
  <input type="checkbox" value="2">Check 2
</div>
```

Please let me know where I've misinterpreted your question.